# how to make a side nav bar?

Tags: css, html

I am trying to make a side-nav bar for a website assignment and I am trying to utilize grid to lay everything out. I am splitting the body into two columns. One for the nav and the other column is for content. However, The grid doesn't seem to like what I am doing and I am totally lost. container two seems to be working correctly but container one is just all over the place, I cant even split it into 4 equal rows that fill up the whole height of the page...Can someone please help me explain what I am doing wrong and how I can fix it? much appreciate!

```css
body{
    background: #5f2072; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, #5f2072 0%, #183661 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #5f2072 0%,#183661 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, #5f2072 0%,#183661 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#5f2072', endColorstr='#183661',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 15% 85%;
    margin:0;
}

.container{
    background-color:white;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:15px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 25%,25%,25%,25%;
}
p{
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Explore & Imagine</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/main.css" />
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
        <p>this is something else</p>
        <p>this is something else</p>
        <p>this is something else</p>
        <p>this is something else</p>
        
</div>
    
  <div class="container2">
    <p>this is something else</p>
  </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue are the commas on the `grid-template-rows` line. Just remove those and it should work just fine.

```
.container{
    background-color:white;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:15px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 25% 25% 25% 25%;
}
```

Comment: aaaaahhhhh! silly mistake. But do you know why the bar isn't extended all the way to the bottom and is there a solution for that?